# What type of unit are flaps settings in?

Tags: flaps

When the flaps are deployed there are different increments on the control lever. When they are set to, say flaps 10 or 40 what is the number indicating?

Comment: The units are degrees. See the dupe in Pondlife's comment for degrees of what angle.

Comment: Thanks for the redirect. I did search but did not find that post. The site search does not seem to be all that effective at locating relevant posts.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunately true. Often Google is better at finding stuff on SE than SE's own search function.